# Querying event viewer in cmd

Tags: windows, windows-10, cmd.exe, event-log, event-viewer

Various sources such as [this one](https://www.windows-commandline.com/event-viewer-command-line/) suggest using a `eventquery.vbs` on the system to query the event log from cmd.  Apparently my stock install of Windows 10 is missing that file:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1052]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Me>cd \Windows\System32

C:\Windows\System32>cscript eventquery.vbs
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.812
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Input Error: Can not find script file "C:\Windows\System32\eventquery.vbs".
```

Nor does it seem to be anywhere else on the system:

```
C:\>dir /a-d /b /s eventquery.vbs
File Not Found
```

How can I query the system event logs from cmd?  Power Shell is not an option.  Specifically I'm trying to query logon failures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventquery.vbs is included with Windows Server 2003, but is now [deprecated](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/ff935312(v=ws.11)).

The article you linked to mentions the Wevtutil tool. I'm not familiar with it myself, but the documentation is [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wevtutil).